# Serializer perform_create not being called

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm a little messed here with this thing... Lost few hours and did try lots of variants of this code, but with no success.

I need create an related object called `ContaCorrente` to each user as `Usuario` when it creates an account.

Those are my models:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    """Classe que ira gerir o cliente final, cadastrado via APP ou Webapp"""
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    .... FOR THE SAKE OF BREVITY

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome + ' ' + self.sobrenome

class ContaCorrente(models.Model):
    """Controle financeiro do Cliente/Usuario cadastrado"""
    pontos = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    saldo_reais = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='conta_corrente')
```

And this is my Serializers:

```
class ContaCorrenteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ContaCorrente
    fields = ('pontos', 'saldo_reais', 'usuario_id')


class UsuariosSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    conta_corrente = ContaCorrenteSerializer(read_only=True)
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = (
        'id',
        'nome',
        'sobrenome',
        'telefone',
        ...
        FOR THE SAKE OF BREVITY
        ...
        'updated_at',
        'conta_corrente'
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        conta = ContaCorrente.objects.create(usuario_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'), saldo_reais=0, pontos=0)
        conta.save()
        serializer.save()
        return serializer
```

I did try lots and lots of variants of this code, but can't find where it explodes.

The `Usuario` model get persisted, but the `ContaCorrente` not! Someone has any help to give? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such method as `perform_create` in parent classes.
Try to use `create` instead. Source [code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L169).

Comment: I used `perform_create` because of oficial documentation: `http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-prepost-save-hooks`... just changed, try and no success again

Comment: w8, i think now its my fault... deploying again, and try... 1 minute

Comment: now appears an error: `'UsuariosSerializer' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`

Comment: @RaphaelSchubert Create method takes validated_data as argument. Try to replace sels.kwargs with validated_data. Look example here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances